# What is a top shadow for text?

Tags: css

I got a requirement for text that looks like this:

> Top shadow: 2px, #000, 75%

What does that mean? Is that just a `text-shadow`? What's the 75% mean?

Comment: 75% = transparency of the shadow.  2px = thinkness of shadow.  #000 = Black - the color of the shadow.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/top-shadow/

Comment: It would probably be best to ask the one that gave you the requirement, wouldn't it? Everything else is guess-work, which most of the time is expensive and probably leads to the wrong solution. One of the biggest problems in software development is that for some reason people tend to rather guess than just talk to each other.

Comment: there is no `top-shadow` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not valid `text-shadow`.

May be you need such example (with correct syntax):

```
text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
```

or

```
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75); /* down shadow */
```

*Notes:*
`rgba(0, 0, 0, .75)` = `#000` with 75% opacity

**Updates:** @[Xander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035609/1057730) found technique which you are asked us about. In it `box-shadow` with css generated content are using:

```
body:before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Top Shadow**, as described in this [post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/top-shadow/), uses CSS3's `box-shadow` and the `:before` pseudo selector to add a shadow under the browsers bar by targeting the `body` element.

There is no `top-shadow` property in CSS, regarding the `Top shadow: 2px, #000, 75%` bit. There is however `text-shadow` & `box-shadow`.

Comment: @Luca Yeap, it's just a name given to the technique.

Comment: Also it would be fine to add `box-shadow` example for OP: `box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);`